# c# there is no relevant app.config after release

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

can somebody please tell me how to treat with app.config? It created itself when I created some values in app.Properties. I set the code file to "CopyAlways". But, when I compile application in debug or release mode, edit config manualy(with Notepad) and start application, it behaves like there are no changes in config file. I tried to change app.config, appname.exe.config and even appname.vschost.exe.config.

What is even more interesting for me is that I can build an app, then copy source files (appname.exe and dll files) without any config file to any new folder, and start an application. It connect to server, despite the fact, that there is no config, where is stored IP.

I found only questions about changing app.config during runtime by code. But this is not I want. I have config for data, that dont change a lot. And .settings for user settings (color of record in datagrid etc).

I tought, that config is read everytime app started. Do I realy have to create my own config file, which will be in the same folder as exe and will be read everytime app starts?

Only support I found on msdn is how to create app.config.

Comment: are these settings UserSettings or ApplicationSettings?

Comment: Have you looked at app config transformations? If there is no native support from Visual Studio for your project type, I would recommend looking at [Slow Cheetah extension](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Slow+Cheetah+extension).

Comment: I manage them trought Properties on tab Settings. Scope is set to User. But the same situation is when I set it to Application.

Answer (score 1):

You should not change the properties of **App.config** to "Copy Always".

When you build your application, the compiler creates a **YourAppName.exe.config** file in your output directory, which contains exactly the same values as your **App.config** file.

If you later change the values from **YourAppName.exe.config** this will be visible when you start your app, without needing to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to copy your app.config or set it as "CopyAlways".

When you build visual studio copy it automatically renaming it applicationName.exe.config

so if your applicaion is: MyApplication.exe you should find in the bin the file MyApplication.exe.config

You are confusing app.config with application settings which are stored in the file user.config inside UserProfile directory.

[Application Settings Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx)

[Application Settings Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx)

They are meant to be used to store user preference as backgroundcolor, visualizzation preferences etc etc

Instead if you want a config value easily changeable you should use the appSettings node in app.config

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key="ServerIp" value="0.0.0.0"/>
</appSettings>
```

and access it from your code:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerIp"]
```

[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx)

Comment: I found that. But all I want to do is build release and copy this app to several computers, where every computer will have some special settings. And if sometimes server addres change, I want to go to the app folder, locate config, open it in notepad, edit IP and save. When app start after this update, it will connect to another server. I can change every possible config, but it seems like app is independent on any config file. It seems like the app makes its own config file, not visible for me.

Comment: @MartinPotvrzenejBrabec did you try to use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings?

Comment: So I have to build app.config by myself? I wanted to use graphic interface from visual studio. By the way I dont know why, but the application dont react on changes made by this graphic interface too.

Comment: SOLVED. While compilation, application makes its own copy of config and setted values save somewhere in the exe itself. Then, when I copy only exe and dll files for mysql, application run and because there is no config, default values are used (on application and user scope). If there is config, application use this app.config values for application scope and user.config from LocalUserAppDataPath for user scope.

Answer (score 0):

Settings of an application that are in UserScope are stored under [Application.LocalUserAppDataPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.localuserappdatapath.aspx) (Normally this is `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\` as base path + the following schema `\CompanyName\ProductName\ProductVersion`). So when you run your application a user.config is stored in this folder and is used for further starts of your application.

The app.config of your application only contains the default values if no user.config is found in the path above.

Open your explorer and check the path of Application.LocalUserAppDataPath if there is a .config file of your application. If so remove it or change the settings in this file.

Comment: So, if I set the scope to Application, it should get the informations from app.config, isn't it? But even if I set Application scope, I am still able make new build, copy exe and dll files to new location and thet start and connect to server. But server IP is always retrieved from app.config (appname.Properties.Settings.Default.mysqlServer).